# Prometheus vector search not include certain labels

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have a lot metrics but there are three metrics which I do not want to include as below

```
appName{monitor="prometheus",status="200",uri="/**/favicon.ico"}
appName{monitor="prometheus",status="404",uri="/**"}
appName{monitor="prometheus",status="200",uri="/actuator/health"}
.....
```

My query is

```
appName{uri!~ "/actuator.*| /** |/**/favicon.ico" }
```

But I got error shows Error executing query:

> parse error at char 30: error parsing regexp: invalid nested repetition operator: `**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't like it :) you have to escape '*'

In my case I had somethnig like:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{"/**"}
http_server_requests_seconds_count{"/webjars/**"}
```

and this query filtered it out:

```
http_server_requests_seconds_count{uri!~ "/\\*\\*|/webjars/\\*\\*"}
```

Comment: Hi Freak, so I have to build to seperated query to achieve this right?

Comment: Separated? No, just modify your query to escape double * and remove whitespace after |